# Is it necessary to have a Localizable.strings file if you do not want to localize any strings?

Tags: ios, string, internationalization

I am learning how to make IOS apps from an Android background. In Android you should put most/all of your strings that are visible to the user in a `strings.xml` file even if your app is not going to be translated.

That means if you set the title of a button/set the text of the Android equivalent of a "UILabel" you will fetch the string from the `strings.xml` file.

I am not going to localize my IOS app. Since this is the case, is it normal to just do:

```
         exampleUIButton.setTitle("Test string", forState: .Normal)
```

Or should "Test String" be stored in a `Localized.strings` file?

Comment: Absolutely normal not to store it, Xcode has English by default. But if you want to support some other language - you should create `Localized.strings` file for additional language.

Comment: Sorry for the typo - the right name is Localizable.strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not mandatory using Localized.strings is a very good habit to get into. It will it be much easier to add localizations should you change your mind later, because you don't have to search your entire project for strings. With it you have all your strings in one location. And the difference in code is really not that big:

```
exampleUIButton.setTitle("Test string", forState: .Normal)
```

vs

```
exampleUIButton.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("str_test", comment: ""), forState: .Normal)
```

Other benefits are ease of sharing sets of strings between projects, spell checking and increased visibility of strings in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

If you are learning to program for iOS then you should get in the habit of using the localized string calls even if you never intend to localize your app. It takes repetion to force yourself to do this.

If you are absolutely consistent about using the `NSLocalizedString` call (or it's variants) for every single display string, then localizing your app becomes trivial to do. If you miss any then those strings can't be localized without code changes.

Code that you are absolutely certain will never be used again has a tendency to live on, and code that you are sure will never be localized has a tendency to need to be localized at some future date.

If the Localized.strings file doesn't exist then the `NSLocalizedString` call is effectively a no-op, but it's still a good idea to use it religiously.